# Inputting range of ports with nmap & optparser

Tags: python, ports, nmap

This is the script

```
import nmap
import optparse

def nmapScan(tgtHost,tgtPort):
    nmScan = nmap.PortScanner()
    nmScan.scan(tgtHost,tgtPort)
    state=nmScan[tgtHost]['tcp'][int(tgtPort)]['state']
    print "[*] " + tgtHost + " tcp/"+tgtPort +" "+state

def main():
    parser = optparse.OptionParser('-H <target host> -p <target port>')
    parser.add_option('-H', dest='tgtHost', type='string', help='specify target host')
    parser.add_option('-p', dest='tgtPort', type='string', help='specify target port[s] separated by comma')
    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()

    tgtHost = options.tgtHost
    tgtPorts = str(options.tgtPort).split(',')

    if (tgtHost == None) | (tgtPorts[0] == None):
        print parser.usage
        exit(0)
    for tgtPort in tgtPorts:
        nmapScan(tgtHost, tgtPort)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I try to enter a range of ports in the command line, I get this error. Could someone help me out? I'm a newbie to python. Thanks in advance!!

```
    :~$ python nmapScan.py -H 192.168.1.6 -p 20-25
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nmapScan.py", line 27, in <module>
    main()
  File "nmapScan.py", line 23, in main
    nmapScan(tgtHost, tgtPort)
  File "nmapScan.py", line 7, in nmapScan
    state=nmScan[tgtHost]['tcp'][int(tgtPort)]['state']
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '20-25'
```

Comment: Well, you parse lists of ports by splitting them on commas, and even say so in the option help string - why would you expect a port range in the format `m-n` to just work?

Comment: If you refer to my post, I'm a newbie to python. I'd appreciate some help.

Comment: @Shane, use `python nmapScan.py  -H 192.168.1.6 -p 20,25` but I think you will have more errors

Comment: Thanks for the practical response, Padraic. When I enter it that way, It seems to only scan port 20 and 25.

Comment: Hmm, I get: TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

Comment: @Shane, I will add a working script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to distinguish between those two different formats, and if the `m-n` range format is used, split at '-' to get the boundaries, create the list of port using `range()`, and set `tgtPorts` to that range.

Here's a function to implement this. You can simply plug it into your code by doing

```
tgtPorts = parse_port_spec(options.tgtPort)
```

instead of your current `tgtPorts = str(options.tgtPort).split(',')`:

```
def parse_port_spec(spec):
    if ',' in spec:
        # Port list
        ports = spec.split(',')
    elif '-' in spec:
        # Port range
        start, end = map(int, spec.split('-'))
        ports = range(start, end + 1)
    else:
        # Single port
        ports = [spec]
    return map(int, ports)
```

Note however that this still does not support the full [nmap port range specification syntax](http://nmap.org/book/man-port-specification.html). You can only use a comma separated list, or a range defined by `m-n`, but not both.

See the documentation for [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) and [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) for details on how those functions work.

Answer (score 0):

```
import nmap
import optparse

def nmapScan(tgtHost,tgtPort):
    nmScan = nmap.PortScanner()
    nmScan.scan(tgtHost,tgtPort)
    state = nmScan[tgtHost]['tcp'][int(tgtPort)]['state']
    print "[*] " + tgtHost + " tcp/"+tgtPort +" "+state


def main():
    parser = optparse.OptionParser('-H <target host> -p <target port>')
    parser.add_option('-H', dest='tgtHost', type='string', help='specify target host')
    parser.add_option('-p', dest='tgtPort', type='string', help='specify target port[s] separated by comma')
    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()
    if not options.tgtHost or not options.tgtPort:
        print parser.usage
        exit(0)
    tgtHost = options.tgtHost
    ports = options.tgtPort
    tgtPorts = options.tgtPort.split(',') if "," in options.tgtPort else map(str,range(int(ports.split("-")[0]),int(ports.split("-")[1]+1))) 
    for tgtPort in tgtPorts:
        nmapScan(tgtHost, tgtPort)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Like I said in a comment you should really use some try/excepts to avoid your script crashing.

```
~$ python nm.py -H 10.10.10.100 -p 20-25
[*] 10.10.10.100  tcp/20 closed
[*] 10.10.10.100  tcp/21 closed
[*] 10.10.10.100  tcp/22 open
[*] 10.10.10.100  tcp/23 closed
[*] 10.10.10.100  tcp/24 closed

$ python nm.py -H 10.10.10.100  -p 20,21
[*] 10.10.10.100  tcp/20 closed
[*] 10.10.10.100  tcp/21 closed

~$ python nm.py -H 10.10.10.100 
-H <target host> -p <target port>
```

As per the [documentation](http://xael.org/norman/python/python-nmap/) you can use `nmap.PortScanner()` which takes a string in the form `20-25` for a range which you could just use that in  your script, parse the dict to get the output  and make your life easier:

```
In [7]: import nmap

In [8]: nm = nmap.PortScanner()

In [9]: nm = nmap.PortScanner()

In [10]: nm.scan('127.0.0.1', '20-25')
```

We can shorten your script using the proper nmap syntax:

```
import nmap
import optparse

def main():
    parser = optparse.OptionParser('-H <target host> -p <target port>')
    parser.add_option('-H', dest='tgtHost', type='string', help='specify target host')
    parser.add_option('-p', dest='tgtPort', type='string', help='specify target port[s] separated by comma')
    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()
    if not options.tgtHost or not options.tgtPort:
        print parser.usage
        exit(0)
    tgtHost = options.tgtHost
    tgtPorts = options.tgtPort

    nm = nmap.PortScanner()
    res = nm.scan(tgtHost,tgtPorts)
    for port in nm[tgtHost]["tcp"].keys():
        print "[*]  {} tcp/{} {}".format(tgtHost,port,res["scan"][tgtHost]["tcp"][int(port)]["state"])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


~$ python nm.py -H 10.10.10.100 -p 20-25
[*]  10.10.10.100  tcp/20 closed
[*]  10.10.10.100  tcp/21 closed
[*]  10.10.10.100  tcp/22 open
[*]  10.10.10.100  tcp/23 closed
[*]  10.10.10.100  tcp/24 closed
[*]  10.10.10.100  tcp/25 open
```

Comment: How setting `tgtPorts` to `'20-25'` would solve his problem is beyond me. That would just iterate over the characters of that string, and then fail when `'-'` is passed to `int()` (after pointlessly scanning single digit ports).

Comment: You'd need to split at `'-'` to get the boundaries, create the list of port using `range()`, and set `tgtPorts` to that range.

Comment: @LukasGraf, the documentation suggests that you pass the string 20-25 for a range, I presumed that was the case so I avoided manually splitting and casting.

Comment: Huh? What documentation? From the line `state=nmScan[tgtHost]['tcp'][int(tgtPort)]['state']` from the traceback it's pretty clear how it works, no?

Comment: @LukasGraf, I will add an example just to clarify it for you

Comment: `PortScanner()` may take that range directly as an argument, but your original code still would have failed in the way I described if you leave that `for tgtPort in tgtPorts` loop in there. Also, that's probably not the point of [this exercise](https://github.com/Eid010n/Violent-Python/blob/master/Chapter%202/python-nmap.py).